# Laravel CSRF middleware is not checking X-CSRF-TOKEN request header

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, csrf, middleware

Middleware:

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }

}
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'wrong-token-to-test',
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': 'another-wrong-token-to-test',
    }
});
```

Blade:

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "{{url("login/$user")}}",
      data: {
         "email": $("#email").val(),
         "password": CryptoJS.SHA256($('#password').val()).toString(),
         "_token": "{{csrf_token()}}"
      }
})
```

Even using the wrong Http header value ('wrong-token-to-test') for csrf token does not result in any token mismatching exception. The request is handled normally. Does that mean Laravel is not checking for the X-CSRF-TOKEN header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel **first** tries to get the CSRF token from the parameter called `_token` in the `get` or `post`, and if missing, **THEN** it tries to get it from a `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. Here is the implementation logic in the code in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken`, method `tokensMatch`  :

```
$token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
```

But you are already effectively including the `_token` parameter  (and with correct value) in your ajax post:

```
"_token": "{{csrf_token()}}"
```

So it doesn't matter what you send in the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header.